# Change ffplay spectrogram colours

Tags: ffmpeg, command-line, ffplay

How can I make the live spectrogram that ffplay renders while playing audio use colours?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [showspectrum](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#showspectrum-1) filter is what you're looking for.

To force ffplay to use colours:

```
ffplay -f lavfi "amovie=audio.m4a,asplit[a][out0];[a]showspectrum=color=intensity:slide=1[out1]"
```

`outN` - non-documented [output link names](https://git.videolan.org/?p=ffmpeg.git;a=blob;f=libavdevice/lavfi.c;h=246f7dff3b3169715fe2683aa8660171edffd1b9;hb=HEAD#l173).

To generate video:

```
ffmpeg -i audio.m4a -lavfi showspectrum=color=magma:slide=1 spectrum.mp4
```

[image: live spectrogramm]

Comment: The ffplay command shows the spectrum in colour, but doesn't play the audio

Comment: Just add the audio stream :) See updated answer.

Comment: The video generated ends, before all the last graphics is out of the scope (and the window fully black). How can is this to control, is there a way to make a video which is for some seconds longer than the audio?

Comment: @Student, to make the resulting video longer you should add the longer input for the `showspectrum` filter, e.g. you can pad the source audio with silence: `ffmpeg -i audio.mp3 -filter_complex '[0:a]apad=pad_dur=5s[a_padded];[a_padded]showspectrum=color=magma:slide=1' spectrum.mp4`. Moreover to smooth the video's end you may apply fade out filter: `[0:a]apad=pad_dur=5s[a_padded];[a_padded]showspectrum=color=magma:slide=1[spectrum];[spectrum]fade=type=out:start_frame=130:nb_frames=56`. Calculations of the offset from the end is on your own ;)